# Performance issue when back button is clicked codenameone

Tags: codenameone

my app is almost ready but there are some performance issues.

1)when i click back button (lets say that goes to main form)it takes 4-5 sec to go to previous form and if i click back btn 2-3 times on that period, the main form will appear 2-3 times. Why is that? there is only one main form so it should appear only once no matter how many times i click back btn.

2) isn't it possible to kill everything that is going on, once the back btn is clicked to perform the back action in an instance. I want to perform back action as soon as possible

following is my code for back action:

```
Toolbar t = new Toolbar();
        t.setUIID("Title1");
        f.setToolBar(t);
        Command news = new Command(" ") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                showForm("Home", this);
            }
        };
        news.putClientProperty("uiid", "BackCommand");
        f.setBackCommand(news);
        t.addCommandToLeftBar(news);
```

Comment: How was this form that contains your back button called from your back form?

Comment: not frm back form, i have a form named news. I kept back btn  as above. If i click that back button 2-3 times it slides back to home form multiple times.

Comment: My question was how did you arrive at the form above? From which form? Did you use showForm(), form.showBack() or form.show()?

Comment: i did showForm() and in other forms i did it from gui command as well. From main form named "Home". there are no of buttons there where i kept showform() in btn actionlistener.

Comment: About killing tasks when you go back, you can always do that yourself since those are your tasks to kill. You need to track what you are doing and release resources that are no longer needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `showForm()` method, you are creating a new instance of the referenced GUI form, which will initiate it's `beforeShow()` method.

If you perform a long operation in the `beforeShow()`, this will slow down response time. Pressing the back button repeatedly will keep calling the same form multiple times.

Move all your long operations like getting data from webservices to `postShow()` method of your form.

Comment: hello @diamond , does form.show() and form.showBack() also work same as showForm()?

Comment: Almost the same, I will suggest you start hand-coding your forms, it will allow you to use `f.show();` and `f.showBack();`... which are very useful for smooth navigation.